# CORS fails to work once I add a JWT authorization header

Tags: reactjs, cors, jwt, axios, flask-restful

I have a Flask backend and a React front-end. The Flask backend is an API that will communicate with other microservices. In development I have my React front-end running on localhost:3000 and the Flask app running on localhost:5000.
Clearly these are different ports which will throw a CORS error by default. So I added Flask_CORS and allowed traffic from localhost:3000. This works and I can now serve GET and POST requests.

I then add my Firebase authentication to the front-end. I receive a JWT and then I want to send the JWT with ech API request to ensure that the user is allowed to make certain requests, which will be validated on the Flask backend.

I added the token_id to the headers in the Axios request to my back-end, but now I am getting the following error:

> localhost/:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/items' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

When I examine the network tab I notice that without the JWT the request passes through fine. See below for header content:

- General:

  - Request URL: http://localhost:5000/items
  - Request Method: GET
  - Status Code: 200 OK
  - Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:5000
  - Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
- Response Headers:

  - **Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000**  <--This line is my concern
  - Content-Length: 37
  - Content-Type: application/json
  - Date: Fri, 06 Sep 2019 09:10:10 GMT
  - Server: Werkzeug/0.15.5 Python/3.7.4
  - Vary: Origin
- Request Headers:

  - Provisional headers are shown
  - Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
  - Origin: http://localhost:3000
  - Referer: http://localhost:3000/
  - Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
  - User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36

I then only add the JWT to the Authorization header config of an Axios interceptor and now the request fails with the following headers present in the Network tab:

- General:

  - Request URL: http://localhost:5000/items
  - Request Method: OPTIONS
  - Status Code: 200 OK
  - Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:5000
  - Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
- Response Headers:

  - Allow: POST, OPTIONS, HEAD, GET
  - Content-Length: 0
  - Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
  - Date: Fri, 06 Sep 2019 09:14:46 GMT
  - Server: Werkzeug/0.15.5 Python/3.7.4
- Request Headers:

  - Provisional headers are shown
  - Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
  - Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
  - Origin: http://localhost:3000
  - Referer: http://localhost:3000/
  - Sec-Fetch-Mode: no-cors
  - User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36

I noticed that the Access-Control-Allow-Origin disappears when the Authorization header is added and instead an Access-Control_Request-Headers is present.

The code of interest in the front end is below

```
import axios from 'axios';
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import 'firebase/auth';

const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:5000/',
});

instance.interceptors.request.use(config => {
    const id_token = firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken();
    config.headers = { Authorization: id_token}; <---Commenting out this line works
    return config
}, error => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
})
export default instance;
```

I do not know how or why the CORS fails to work as soon as a JWT is added. I suspect it is because once the JWT is added there is a pre-flight request. But I have changed nothing on the server side so I am puzzled as to why the server would not provide a suitablelCORS response just because a JWT is added.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: By the way: if youa re using create-react-app you can add a proxy to your package.json file: [link](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define CORS at the top of the main file, it will allow all the CORS requests

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route("/api/test")
def test_cors():
  return "CORS allowed"
```

Comment: I was using the decorator syntax: @cross_origin(origins ='*', expose_headers='Authorization'). Unfortunately it gives the same result

Comment: Can you try adding origins and support_credentials as well?

Comment: Can you try without decorators like above?

Comment: I took everything out of the  CORS(app) call (i.e. not arguments other than app). And then used the decorator with no arguments (i.e. @cross_origin()) and it is working. It seems passing in arguments to CORS() interfered with something.

Comment: Good to hear that, you can also delete @cross_origin because when you define CORS in the top of the file it will apply all the routes of your app, see [official docs here!](https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#simple-usage)